# Styling a ID that is generated GUID

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm looking to style a specific jqueryui dialog so that it centers itself.
The problem is that the ID always changes because it's generated as a GUID in the controller. How do i select an ID that's always changing so i can center it?

This is in the controller

```
ViewBag.UniqueID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

This is in the cshtml

```
<div class="__helpItemArea" id='@String.Format("div{0}", ViewBag.UniqueID)' style='@(ViewBag.WindowWidth==null ? "" : String.Format("width:{0}px;",ViewBag.WindowWidth)) @(ViewBag.WindowHeight==null ? "" : String.Format("height:{0}px;",ViewBag.WindowHeight)) '>
```

As you can see, this generates a GUID to the div ID, there's no way i can select a specific div to actually style it. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: use `class` to select the div if the `id` is generated dynamically.

Comment: @Sushil, Well that's what I tried, but the class is from a template. that is used by other areas of the application. So it will affect the other areas that I don't want it to. If only i could use another ID.

Comment: try giving a `data` attribute then

Comment: I'm not familiar with doing that, could you possibly give me an example?

Comment: so you can try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/oetkL1bj/. here I am selecting the `div` tags based on the `data` attribute. try it and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: did it work for you @Levetica?

Comment: I'm trying and i'm very confused to be honest. I must be missing something small.

Comment: can you show the updated html with `data` attributes?

Comment: 'code' <div class="__helpItemArea" id='@String.Format("div{0}", ViewBag.UniqueID)' data-item='helpArea' style='@(ViewBag.WindowWidth==null ? "" : String.Format("width:{0}px;",ViewBag.WindowWidth)) @(ViewBag.WindowHeight==null ? "" : String.Format("height:{0}px;",ViewBag.WindowHeight)) '>

Comment: and for the css i added  .div[data-item="helpArea"] {left: 51.0em; top: 1.7em;}

Comment: the `css` should be `div[data-item="helpArea"]` and not `.div[data-item="helpArea"]` notice the dot. its not required.

Comment: Oh I see, yes that worked, but the problem is that it's applying the css to the other divs that use the data-item="helparea". Would i be able to do this inside the js of the specific dialog that I want to target? Here's the JS for that specific dialog http://imgur.com/SWcg3xt

Comment: yeah that's what the fiddle was doing. you can use js to style your dialog

Comment: In this JS, i'm not sure where to put the CSS. The area that I want these CSS changes to affect is ".__helpItemArea"   - http://imgur.com/SWcg3xt

Comment: do you want it on page load or when something is clicked?

Comment: Well I just want it to center the dialog when the button is clicked. So the latter i guess.

Comment: so you can just apply the css in the button click event of your button.

Comment: Okay so it would look something like this? $(".__helpitem").off("click").css("{left: -51.0em; top: -1.7em;}");

Comment: is this the click event where you want to apply the css?

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure. I want the css to be applied to the dialog. The dialog is hidden until it's clicked....So i'm honestly just not sure at this point? :(

Comment: so your code should be `$('.__helpItem').on('click', function(){
 $('div[data-item="helpArea"]').each(function(){
  $(this).css('{left: -51.0em; top: -1.7em;}');
 });
});`

Comment: That worked, oh my gosh. you've got no idea how long i've spent on this. It's almost embarassing.

Comment: he he.. great. let me post this as a solution then. please upvote it and mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since your `div` `Id's` are dynamically generated and they're `GUID`'s and you don't want to use the `class` since it's being used on other elements as well. I'd suggest you to use jquery **[data](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** attributes.

so let's assume that you have a data attribute `data-item='helpArea'` on your `div`

so to style these div's you can just use the following code

```
$('#test').on('click', function() {
    $('div[data-item="helpArea"]').each(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'slategrey');
        $(this).css('color', 'white');
    });
});
```

here's a sample **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/oetkL1bj/)**. hope this helps.

Comment: This Solved the problem.

Comment: glad was able to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use the attribute starts with selector

```
[id^="div"]{
   /*styles here*/
}
```

Comment: Hrm. i've never used that before. so it would look like this exactly i guess?                                                                                           [id^="div"]{
  background-color: #fff; border: 1px solid #fff; border-radius: 4px; box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5); display: none; left: -50.0em; top: -1.7em; right: 0; min-width: 55em; max-width: 55em; position: absolute; z-index: 1000; 
}

Comment: It's not working no, it's targeting the first dialog. There's a dialog box that opens normally and then there's a help button inside this dialog that opens another dialog. This second dialog is the one with the unique guid ID that's generated each time on document load. and that's the one that i want to target.